# How to store a mysql string in a javascript variable using jsp

Tags: javascript, mysql, jsp

I want to store mysql strings in a javascript array variable. I am using jsp for server-side.

I tried it in three ways. All the three aren't working. Need some help.

***Attempt-1*:**

```
<script>
        var name = [];
  <%
        st=con.prepareStatement("select name from company");
        rs=st.executeQuery();
        while(rs.next()){
            String s = rs.getString(1);
  %>
            name.push(<%=s%>);          
  <%
        } 
  %>
</script>
```

---

***Attempt-2*:**

```
<script>
        var name = [];
  <%
        st=con.prepareStatement("select name from company");
        rs=st.executeQuery();
        while(rs.next()){
  %>
            name.push(<%=rs.getString(1)%>);            
  <%
        } 
  %>
</script>
```

---

***Attempt-3*:**

```
<script>
        var name = [];
  <%
        st=con.prepareStatement("select name from company");
        rs=st.executeQuery();
        while(rs.next()){
  %>
            name.push(<%out.print(rs.getString(1));%>);         
  <%
        } 
  %>
</script>
```

---

All the three attempts showed the same result and error after processing.

**Interpreted Code:**

```
<script>
        var name = [];
        name.push(tcs);
        name.push(wipro);
</script>
```

**Error:**

```
ReferenceError: tcs is not defined
```

---

Comment: Look at your generated code.  Why do you think that should work? You need to escape your strings before outputting JS.

Comment: @SLaks: Can't get you. I'm a noob.

Comment: Try putting quotes, `name.push("<%=s%>")`

Comment: `name.push(tcs);` is not valid Javascript (you don't have a `tcs` variable)

Comment: And what if the name contains a `"` or a backslash?

Comment: How should I add it? But, rs.getString(int) must always return a string, isn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add `"` around your string also you should javascript encode it(I think apache has a library that will do this for you):

```
<script>
        var name = [];
  <%
        st=con.prepareStatement("select name from company");
        rs=st.executeQuery();
        while(rs.next()){
            String s = StringEscapeUtils.escapeJavaScript(rs.getString(1));
  %>
            name.push("<%= s %>");          
  <%
        } 
  %>
</script>
```

Try using this Apache library to escape the java string based on javascript rules: [StringEscapeUtils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringEscapeUtils.html)

Javascript is trying to interpret `name.push(tcs);` `tcs` as a variable which in this case `tcs` has not been declared or initialized it is undefined.  Instead you want javascript to interpret `tcs` as a string so you need quotes around it `"tcs"` or in your case `"<%= s %>"`.

Comment: thank you. i tried adding `"` like `'"'+<%= s %>+'"'`. it showed the same error. that's y i decided to post a question here. cudn't get what i wanted even after i googled.

Comment: @Ramvignesh don't add `'"'+` just `"` do it exactly how i have it in my answer...

Comment: @Ramvignesh `name.push("<%= s %>");` exactly like that.